# how to rotate the bar graph so i can show straight in google chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

[image]

Actaully I want to get the bargraph in vertical position but my bar graph is coming with rotating 90 degree.I want to show them straight to the screen.I searched for many links but didnt get the correct result.I have mentioned the json data below.I havent putted any rotating options in my code.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    google.charts.load('current', {
          packages: ['corechart']
        }).then(function () {
          $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/FRA-UI/api/report34graph/all',
            dataType: 'json'
          }).done(function (jsonData) {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'realname');
            data.addColumn('number', 'qualityone');
            data.addColumn('number', 'qualitytwo');
            data.addColumn('number', 'qualitythree');


            $.each(jsonData, function (index, row) {
              data.addRow([
                row.realName,
                row.qualityOne,
                row.qualityTwo,
                row.qualityThree
              ]);
            });

         // Optional; add a title and set the width and height of the chart
           // var options = {'title':'My Average Day', 'width':550, 'height':400};


            var logOptions = {
                    title: 'Number of stems by DBH class',

                    legend: 'none',
                    width: 2000,
                    height: 700,
                    pointSize: 5,

                    series: {
                          0: { pointShape: 'circle' },


                      },
                    hAxis: {
                      title: 'DBH classes'

                    },

                    vAxis: {
                      title: 'No of stems/ha',
                      ticks: [0, 50, 100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500,550,600]
                    }
                  };

            var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, logOptions);
          });
        });
    </script>

  </head>
<title></title>
  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div" ></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

The json data i am getting is :

```
[{"realName":"005-10","qualityOne":0.35,"qualityTwo":1.34,"qualityThree":5.45},{"realName":"010-20","qualityOne":3.84,"qualityTwo":6.46,"qualityThree":16.33},{"realName":"020-30","qualityOne":33.74,"qualityTwo":21.93,"qualityThree":18.0},{"realName":"50<diameter","qualityOne":98.7,"qualityTwo":14.13,"qualityThree":12.14}]
```

Comment: Straight from google docs - "For a vertical version of this chart see Column Charts https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you might be using the wrong chart type.

Check out the Column Chart for the vertical positioning.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart